# Solution with overlapping text ranges.

Tags: javascript, rangy

I have a following problem and looking for hints how to do this with 
rangy or native range object. I have div element that containing following 
text: 
 "This is example text." 
From service I receiving this example json response. 
[{ start: 0, end: 10}, {start: 2, end: 8}] 
I want to add spans that marks text from 0 to 10 and from 2 to 8.
So second span - from 2 to 8 must be added with deviation of the already added span.

Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rangy 1.3 has simple character offset-based getting and setting in the core via [`getBookmark()`](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Range#getbookmarknode-containernode) and [`moveToBookmark()`](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Range#movetobookmarkobject-bookmark) methods of Range. Once you have a range you can split text nodes at the range boundaries, get all the text nodes in the range using `getNodes()` and surround each in turn in a span.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mL0jz0xg/

Code:

```
function highlightCharacterRange(el, start, end) {
    var range = rangy.createRange();
    range.moveToBookmark({
        containerNode: el,
        start: start,
        end: end
    });
    range.splitBoundaries();
    var textNodes = range.getNodes([3]);
    for (var i = 0, textNode, span; textNode = textNodes[i++]; ) {
        span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "highlight";
        textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, textNode);
        span.appendChild(textNode);
    }
}

var container = document.getElementById("container");
highlightCharacterRange(container, 0, 10);
highlightCharacterRange(container, 2, 8);
highlightCharacterRange(container, 7, 14);
```

Comment: I am sorry that I can not give you more than +1.

Comment: Same here, but between the two of us that makes +2!